# XSLT: Use the value of an referenced element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I'd like to get the value of an element, that is referenced by another element via a unique id. For example:

```
<when xml:id="TLI_2" interval="7.683988796743416" since="#T_START"/>
<annotationBlock who="#H-F" start="#TLI_2" end="#TLI_3">
    <u xml:id="Ladida"><incident>
      <desc>TiH</desc>
           </incident><w xml:id="wd1e235">das</w><w xml:id="wd1e237">war</w><w
                    xml:id="wd1e239">die</w><w xml:id="wd1e241">erste</w><w xml:id="wd1e243"
                    >große</w><w xml:id="wd1e245">liebe</w><incident>
                    <desc>schnitt</desc>
                </incident></u>
        </annotationBlock>
```

I need to match the value of the attribute `interval`. The specific when element is referenced by a attribute within `<annotationBlock>`. So my current XSLT-Templates looks something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="annotationBlock/u/w">
 <when>
   <xsl:attribute name="interval">
     <xsl:value-of select="../../From here i don't know what to do"/>
<!-- The value should be the value of the interval-attribute of the referenced when-element -->
   </xsl:attribute>
 </when>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to select the `when` element by its `xml:id` attribute value you can use `id('TLI_2')` to do that so in the context of the `w` elements with the ancestor `annotationBlock` I think you want `id(ancestor::annotationBlock/@start/substring(., 2))` to select the `when` element and of course `id(ancestor::annotationBlock/@start/substring(., 2))/@interval` to select its `interval` attribute.

A compact way to use that inside your template would inside of attribute value template

```
<xsl:template match="annotationBlock/u/w">
 <when interval="{id(ancestor::annotationBlock/@start/substring(., 2))/@interval}">
```